# How to Stop ValidationExpression on Clearing The Text Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

Using an ASP.NET application I have a Textbox as:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NEEDID" runat="server" MaxLength="50" ></asp:TextBox></div>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="AdvNeedIdValidator" runat="server"
ControlToValidate="NEEDID" ErrorMessage="Need ID is numeric."
ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d*\.?\d*$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

and two buttons for `Search` and `Clear Search` for c;earing search box.

```
<asp:Button ID="Adv_SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="Adv_SearchButton_Click"/> 

<asp:Button ID="ClearFilterButton" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="thin-button" runat="server" Text="Clear Search" onclick="ClearFilterButton_Click" />
```

now my problem is even on clearing the search box the `ValidationExpression` is functioning! while it is suppose to only run when the `Search` button clicks!
Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the attribute `CausesValidation="false"` to your clear button. Since your button causes a postback, it is going to validate the content of the `TextBox`.

Better still, consider using Javascript to clear the content of the `TextBox` to improve the user experience by avoiding the postback to your server.

Comment: Thanks Bob it was a great help!